# Mapping lines to columns in *nix

Tags: linux, text, command-line, text-processing

I have a text file that was created when someone pasted from Excel into a text-only email message. There were originally five columns.

```
Column header 1

Column header 2

...

Column header 5

Row 1, column 1

Row 1, column 2

etc
```

Some of the data is single-word, some has spaces. What's the best way to get this data into column-formatted text with unix utils?

Edit: I'm looking for the following output:

```
Column header 1   Column header 2   ...   Column header 5
Row 1 column 1    Row 1 column 2 ...
...
```

I was able to achieve this output by manually converting the data to CSV in vim by adding a comma to the end of each line, then manually joining each set of 5 lines with J. Then I ran the csv through `column -ts,` to get the desired output. But there's got to be a better way next time this comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a perl-one-liner ain't "the best" way, but it should work:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$fields_per_line=5; $field_seperator="\t"; \
  $line_break="\n"}                                        \
  chomp;                                                   \
  print $_,                                                \
  $. % $fields_per_row ? $field_seperator : $line_break;   \
  END{print $line_break}'  INFILE > OUTFILE.CSV
```

Just substitute the "5", "\t" (tabspace), "\n" (newline) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a script that uses readline and counter. When the program reaches that line you want, use cut  command and space as a dilimeter to get the word you want

```
counter=0
lineNumber=3
while read line
do
 counter += 1
 if lineNumber==counter
   do
      echo $line | cut -d" " -f 4
   done
 fi
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was unclear. The output I'm looking for is:
grr, I can't do line breaks in a comment.

Comment: Are the header columns always the same amount? What I am trying to find out is do the number or headers or rows change or are they static? Any way to get a actual example of the text file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the actual data, but the number of columns is static. There are 5 columns, each occupying 10 lines (because of alternating empty lines)